# LibGDX generate a signed APK [NetBeans]

Tags: java, android, libgdx, apk, netbeans-8

How do you generate a signed APK for a LibGDX project? I have had a look at [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-android) page. However, it does not indicate how to build a signed APK with NetBeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can generate unsigned apk then there easy way to signed apk in command line.
First of all you sould to create your apk key using command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\my-release-key.jks" -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias AliasForMyApp
```

You should enter at least one of the fields, for example City or Name.
More about this can find in [official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).

In next step using jarsigner tool sign the applcation:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore "c:/users/alex/desktop/my-release-key.jks" -storepass passformyapp -keypass passformykey "c:/users/alex/desktop/app-release-unsigned.apk" AliasForMyApp
```

You can find more information and examples about this tools. Without Android Studio, I know only this method.